# Gmail Gem - Moving to a label within a label

Tags: ruby, gmail

https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail

I'm having a little trouble moving into a folder within a folder.

on my gmail account i have different "labels" or folders.

```
school # this is a folder
  Class 1 # this is a folder within the school folder

work # this is a folder
  Client 1 # this is a folder within the work folder
```

Now with the ruby gem gmail i can get into the first folder but not into the other.

```
gmail.label("school")
#returns a true statement, i could add to the code above and manipulate emails 
#but if i run something like 
gmail.label("school").label("Class 1")
#this returns an error.
```

My goal is to navigate to the "Class 1" directory to manipulate email

Comment: Still haven't seen anything, I'm going to try require 'net/imap' instead of require 'gmail'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gmail.label('school/Class 1') #this will get you into the directory
```